# is maven required to develop spring based project?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am developing (Single developer) a Spring based project for a Traveling based website.
and this is my first Spring based project, I want to use Maven in my project, because hosting sites like Cloud Bees expecting maven based project for deployment.
Is Maven required to develop Spring based project in Single developer environment.
FYI I am using eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not required.

You can develop in Spring using Ant or Maven or Gradle etc. or nothing at all.

Although it might be easier to do it with Maven (for library management)

Answer (score 1):

It is not required per se, but you will run into some serious pain down the road if you don't use Maven or Gradle.

The first and foremost reason to use Maven or Gradle is to be able to very simply run tasks that occur ofter (like building a war or running the tests) and to be able to declaratively obtain the required dependencies (which in the case of a typical Spring application are plentiful).

If you are just starting to use build tool, I would suggest you take look at Gradle instead of Maven.

Comment: Thanks @kazanaki and geoand, but i don't have knowledge of Maven or Gradle and i don't have enough time to learn these build tools, so I am planning to first start developing the project and when i get time I will use it to learn any of these tools, Can I include any of these build tool in to my project later stages of development?

Comment: @AhmedShareef Yes you can include them in later stages. It might be a little work, but it's definitely doable. I would suggest however you check out https://spring.io/guides which has a bunch of small examples for doing various things in Spring. And of course it has the build file configured